# MYSQL - Prepared Statement NULL handling

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have good number of prepared statements in my MYSQL stored procedure . There is a chance the statement can become NULL ( the dynamically generated SQL statement ) , so to avoid run time exception I am using the below approach always . But since I am using prepared statements a lot , giving NULL check every where looks noisy .

```
   SET @s10=CONCAT('UPDATE tlist  SET total_count=total_count-1 WHERE group_id =',in_location_id,' AND sub_type=',COMPANY_COUNT,' AND sub_id in (',var_companies,')' );
   IF(@s10 is NOT NULL) THEN
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s10;
        EXECUTE stmt;       
   END IF;
```

So is there any other approach that I can follow to mimize the above code into one or two lines ?
( Making statement and executing it together and Null handling together in one step ?)

I know I can run small subroutine and pass the prepared statement to it and do the above check , But want to know if there is any inbuilt MYSQL functionality for it .

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SET @s10=CONCAT('UPDATE tlist  SET total_count=total_count-1 WHERE group_id =',in_location_id,' 
AND sub_type=',COMPANY_COUNT,' AND sub_id in (',var_companies,')' );
IF(!ISNULL(@s10) && LENGTH(trim(@s10)) > 0) THEN
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s10;
    EXECUTE stmt;       
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response . In fact I want to short the above code lines . Thanks again